# Set Rainbird Sprinkler to run on certain days

Tags: sprinkler-system, grass

I have a rainbird ESP-TM2 sprinkler system and in it I have programmed it to

water: Mon/Wed/Fri/Sun

No water: Tue/Thur/Sat

Simple enough but now because of this even odd mess it waters which ever day it feels like. For example it will water on Mon and then water on Tue (even when its not supposed to) and wont water on Wed. It just waters on days that dont make sense.

My question is How can I disable this whole even/odd days and have it only turn on the days I want it? I already googled searched with no help

If I press and hold left and right arrows when on water days setting

- It show ODD
- press again it shows EVEN
- press again and it goes back the main M/Tue/Wed/Thur watering page

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: what are your settings for Program B and C

Comment: program b and c are off. nothing set for them. Only program A

Comment: Do you know where is the Reset

Comment: So just a humidity sensor in the soil and it will do what is needed...

Comment: there has to be a setting to stop even odd days and set to custom days i.e. stop day cycle and days remaninig

Comment: Are you sure the system knows the correct day and time?

Comment: push let+right arrow simultaneously

Comment: @Ruskes see updated question post. there is something about days cycle and days remaining that I am not getting

Comment: I see it, to get out of all the crap, Reset it and start new

Comment: [Here](https://www.rainbird.com/sites/default/files/media/documents/2017-06/man_ESP-TM2_en.pdf) is the manual.  The information you want is on pages 6, 8, and 9.  Including the Reset instructions, which I agree is a good suggestion.  Starting fresh seems easier than unwinding what you've got.  The user interface and documentation are terrible.  Reset then do the exact minimum to get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

ok I got it and this is the most dumbest way this thing works.

- turn the dial till you are on watering days
- adjust the watering days on/off for Mon/Tue/Wed/Thru/Fri and so on
- Now here the trick. **Do NOT TOUCH the left and right arrow** or **go to the days cycle page**. This is where I was making the mistake
- while you are on the Mon/Tue page rotate the dial all the way to ATUO.
- Now it will water ONLY on the days you selected. I cannot believe someone thought this was a brilliant design.

[image]

Comment: I have the same unit. There is a phone app that is easier to use.

Comment: @JD74 but you have to buy an additional $120 WIFI accessory and put it in it to make it work with app. Mine didnt come with one. its extra

Comment: I had the same unit and was having a similar issue (it would turn itself on on what seemed like random days) but rather than give rainbird any more money for the wifi piece, I just replaced the controller with one from RainMachine.  Yes it cost more than the wifi piece but it was also a huge upgrade to my mind.